# Can't change transition on the fly for a transition group

Tags: vue.js, vue-transitions

In my app, clicking a modal's close button makes it disappear with a fade animation whereas swiping it down makes it disappear with a swipe animation. This is done by changing the modal's `<transition name>` based on event.

The same thing doesn't seem to work with a transition group. Am I doing something wrong, or is it actually not possible?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-forked-fdi8l?file=/src/App.vue)

Template:

```
<transition-group :name="itemTransition">
  <div
    v-for="item in items"
    :key="item.id"
    v-hammer:swipe.up="() => onSwipeUp(notification.id)"
  >
  </div>
</transition-group>
```

Script:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      applySwipeTransition: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    itemTransition () {
      return this.applySwipeTransition ? 'swipe' : 'fade'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSwipeUp (id) {
      this.applySwipeTransition = true
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.closeItem(id)
        this.applySwipeTransition = false
      })
    }
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.fade-leave-active {
  animation: fade-out .75s;
}

.swipe-leave-active {
  animation: slide-up .25s;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the timing of component update. You are switching the transition mode back to `fade` in the same update cycle as when the element is closed. Thus, when the next component update is triggered (by removal of the item), the transition is already switched back to `fade`. At this point, you may have guessed that all that needs to be done, is to switch the transition back in the next update, triggered by removal of the item:

```
   onSwipeUp (id) {
     this.applySwipeTransition = true
     this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.closeItem(id)
        this.$nextTick(()=>{
          this.applySwipeTransition = false
        })         
     })
   }
```

Since there are no reasons to wait for component update to close the item, you can simplify the code a bit:

```
   onSwipeUp (id) {
      this.applySwipeTransition = true
      this.closeItem(id)
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.applySwipeTransition = false
      })
    }
```

Here is your working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-forked-60lkk?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Works, thanks! SO doesn't let me grant bounty now, have to wait 4 hours. One question though, in my sandbox I actually (1) set transition to swipe, (2) remove item in next update cycle, (3) set transition back to fade in next update cycle. Why doesn't this work? I understand it's unnecessary to do things in so many successive update cycles, but it should still work since each step is done in chronological order of update cycles isn't it?

Comment: in your code both nextTick() calls (for item removal and switching the transition) are executed synchronously, thus when they are registered they both are waiting for the same update cycle. to be successive, the next nextTick() should be called from within the previous update cycle. this is why you have to nest them. think of them as async function calls. not sure I've explained well, have to admit they are tricky to understand

Comment: No I kind of get you, thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I've worked around with your CSS by manually changing the `name` of the `<transition-group` to either `fade` or `swipe` to see if the there's a problem with the CSS animations.

**Verdict:** The `fade` works. `swipe` only transitions the `list-item` off the page **by a click and drag, not true swipe**, if that concerns you (by the way, my swipe is MacOS swipe - two-finger, no click)

Still, without changing the CodePen, the issue seems to be with your `computed` property where there's nothing telling the `name` to change dynamically even though you've bound it to a `computed` property - the logic for `itemTransition()` seems to always default to `fade` because the `applySwipeTransition` would never equal to "swipe", given that the CSS does work when you manually change `name` to `swipe` (see "Verdict)".

To see where the underlying issue was, I worked around with your `itemTransition()`:

```
computed: {
    itemTransition() {
      return this.applySwipeTransition ? "fade" : "swipe";
    },
```

Switching the order of the `fade` and `swipe` now makes `swipe` work. I hope this gives you some insight into the issue. You may need to create a [custom Vue directive](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html) or [event](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html) to handle the swipe / fade logic if needed.